# Obtener latitud y longitud a partir de una dirección google maps 3

Tags: php, javascript, html5

estoy desarrollando una aplicación web que incluye un mapa de Google Maps API 3 y en el misma página se incluye un campo para colocar una dirección y a través de un botón buscar, posicionar un pin en el mapa.
Ahora bien, tengo este código y funciona bien

```
<script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.608444, lng: -58.3722367},
            zoom: 15
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        });
      }

      function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                position: results[0].geometry.location

            });
          } else {
            alert('La localización no fue satisfactoria por la siguiente razón: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
```

El problema que tengo es que no se como mostrar la latitud y la longitud al mismo tiempo en dos cajas de texto adicionales.
Después también debería poder encontrar una dirección a partir de la latitud y longitud... 
Desde ya muchas gracias la ayuda que puedan darme... 
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });            
            document.getElementById("lat").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById("lon").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

          } else {
            alert('La localización no fue satisfactoria por la siguiente razón: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

Porque existe una forma mas fácil de solucionar con menos código y limpio. como este por ejemplo. funciona igual que la anterior pero con dos linea de condigo, Pruebalo.(Haz que tu código sea lo mas sencillo posible y entendible por supuesto ).

Comment: queda mas ordenado y mas limpio !!! gracias Feder... es verdad funciona perfectamente...

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez no sea la mejor solución, pero,  aquí tienes una alternativa

```
if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });            

            var location =  String(results[0].geometry.location).split(',');   

            document.getElementById("lat").value = location[0].replace("(","");

            document.getElementById("lon").value = location[1].replace(")","");
          } else {
            alert('La localización no fue satisfactoria por la siguiente razón: ' + status);
 }
```

Tener en cuenta el id de los textbox

Comment: FUNCIONO PERFECTO !!! MUCHAS GRACIAS FEDER... lo que no entiendo es porque dices que puede que no sea la mejor solución...